# So how do I get the values from the dictionary based on the selected range in the calendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, range

[Image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBLSK.png)

I am new to Javascript, html and css. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
I have a calendar where you can select a date range. I want to have this range to filter out a dictionary according to the date.

I have created the calendar and the dictionary. Here are the calendar codes and the dictionary codes in my HTML.

I tried debugging using the console.log(). As you can see here, both the key in the dateDict and fromDate are in the same format and also data type, but the dateDict does not recognize fromDate as one of the key  in the dateDict. So how do I get the values from the dictionary based on the selected range in the calendar

```html
<!-- Block for the Calendar --> 
    <div class="calendar">
      <label>From Date</label>
      <input type="date" name="" max="" id="fromDate">
      <br><br>
      <label>To Date</label>
      <input type="date" name="" max="" id="toDate">
      <br><br>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">See Data</button>
    </div>

    <p id="selectedDate"></p>
    
    <!-- Block for Calendar to show error--> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var fromDate;
    $('#fromDate').on('change', function(){
    fromDate = $(this).val();
    $('#toDate').prop('min', function(){
      return fromDate;
    })

  });

</script>

<!-- Storing the Value of the fromDate and toDate --> 
<script>
  var dateDict = {
    "2021-4-1": 1,
    "2021-4-2": 1,
    "2021-4-3": 5,
    "2021-4-4": 1,
    "2021-4-5": 2
  };
  console.log(dateDict);
  console.log(typeof dateDict);
  

  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fromDate").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("toDate").value;
    document.getElementById("selectedDate").innerHTML = x + y;
    console.log(x);
    console.log(typeof x); // x is a string
    console.log(fromDate);
    console.log(typeof fromDate); // is also a string
    console.log(fromDate in dateDict); //but gives false, when both have the same format and data type
    




  }
</script>
```

Comment: `2021-4-1` is not the same string as `2021-04-01`, `fromDate in dateDict` compares the value as well, not just the type.

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for the reply. I edited the dateDict keys and it works so far! :) I am not sure how to mark your answer as the accepted answer

Comment: you're welcome, you can't do that as it's not an answer, it's a comment, and since it was a small change that you needed, i think just a comment should be enough :)

Comment: Hello, im sorry, actually i face another problem, which is that when i try to look for the value from the key, i get undefined instead of the value. e.i console.log(dateDict[fromDate]) shows undefined. .. Hm.. any idea why this happens when i check console.log(fromDate in dateDict) shows true?

Answer (score 0):

The keys in the `dateDict` should match the format that is being returned by the date picker, it is currently missing some zeroes. Correct:

```
var dateDict = {
    "2021-04-01": 1,
    "2021-04-02": 1,
    "2021-04-03": 5,
    "2021-04-04": 1,
    "2021-04-05": 2
  };
```

Also, a bug that I found in the datePicker is that if you select the `to` date first and then select the `from` date, then you can actually mess the logic up, because now `to` date can be before `from` date. To fix this what I've done is whenever `from` date is change the `to` date will get reset.

And if you want the value corresponding to the date from the `dateDict`, you can simply do `dateDict[fromDate]`.

```html
<!-- Block for the Calendar --> 
    <div class="calendar">
      <label>From Date</label>
      <input type="date" name="" max="" id="fromDate">
      <br><br>
      <label>To Date</label>
      <input type="date" name="" max="" id="toDate">
      <br><br>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">See Data</button>
    </div>

    <p id="selectedDate"></p>
    
    <!-- Block for Calendar to show error--> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var fromDate;
    $('#fromDate').on('change', function(){
    fromDate = $(this).val();
    $('#toDate').val(""); // RESET toDate when fromDate is changed
    $('#toDate').prop('min', function(){
      return fromDate;
    })
  });
</script>

<!-- Storing the Value of the fromDate and toDate --> 
<script>
  var dateDict = {
    "2021-04-01": 1,
    "2021-04-02": 1,
    "2021-04-03": 5,
    "2021-04-04": 1,
    "2021-04-05": 2
  };

  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fromDate").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("toDate").value;
    document.getElementById("selectedDate").innerHTML = x + y;
    console.log(fromDate in dateDict); // gives true if fromDate is in dateDict
    console.log(dateDict[fromDate]); // gives the value corresponding to the date
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help! @Annanana

Comment: Hi thank you so much ! this works perfectly. I am so happy!
 However, i think i did not make my aim very clear, which is to select the values from the keys in the dateDict according to the range of date selected

Comment: @Annanana If you found the answer useful, consider upvoting and marking it as an answer for future users to benefit from it.